# CRM Allow duplicate records N:N relationship

Tags: many-to-many, entity, duplicates, crm

I have two entities "A" and "B", where B is a related entity to the parent A. The relationship type is N:N relationship, and I want to add multiple instances of a record from "B". For example I want two instances of the "B_1" record under the record of "A". How can I achieve this?

CRM does not allow it and gives the error:
"A record with these values already exists. A duplicate record cannot be created. Select one or more unique values and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an article about this, you can read it here: [Adding Duplicates in N:N-Relations](http://jonasrapp.cinteros.se/2012/07/adding-duplicates-in-nn-relations.html)

Comment: It will be more beneficial if you can add excerpt of your post in your answer.